Can I output coloured text in PyCharm?
I need coloured text for a game I'm making. Is there any possible way I could do this in PyCharm?
I've tried :
import sys

try:
    color = sys.stdout.shell
except AttributeError:
    raise RuntimeError("Use IDLE")

but of course, it's not idle. How can I fix this?

The editor is irrelevant, whether it be Pycharm or VS Code or IDLE or etc. The more relevant question is which Python libraries allow you colorize the output, and to which terminal are you going to print it out, because the two of them need to be compatible.
